# Conditional Formatting

Tags: xls

I am looking to format a cell based on the value on another cell:
The value of cell A1 = 7:03
The value of cell A2 = 7:00

I would like cell A2 to turn red if the value of A1 is within 3 of A2. IF A1 is 6:56 not formatted but if it is 6:57 or greater, then A2 would turn "red."

Answer (score 0):

If your values are hours:minutes then please select A2 and try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=ABS(A2-A1)<=3/(24*60)
```

If minutes:seconds then, in principle, replace `60` by `3600` but this might not quite work in all cases because of approximation.

If the values are strings then a general case would require conversion to numeric format.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution lies with 'Conditional Formating'.
Go to the help screen and research how to use this.

You can create formulas there to change the format of cells.
Might also look for U-tube info on it for add'l detail.